# What kind of options are there for very high bandwidth long distance data links?

Tags: radio, data, hd

I'm considering a future product. A high definition (720p) video transmitter. Ideally a compressed MPEG link would be used but this would still require at least 80 Mbit/s. I'm not looking at a simple solution, and I don't even think it's possible without high cost and big transmitting gear, but what is everyone's opinions? What about sending component video over long distances? I'm talking about 10km or so and the link must be wireless. The nodes may move, one would likely be an RC plane.

Comment: For high bandwidth and long distance, you can't beat a 747 full of DVDs - high latency though

Comment: Good joke... somehow I'm thinking this is an impossible problem, which is why there are no small long distance HD video links.

Comment: Your question doesn't say wireless, is a wired solution acceptable?

Comment: It'd need to be wireless.

Comment: I was considering something like WAN or even WiFi with a directional antenna, but I'm not even sure if they can hit 80 Mbit/s peak at 10km distance, or even if it's possible to go that far.

Comment: Are the nodes stationary?

Comment: The nodes can move. One is an RC plane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use Microhard Systems 1.5 Mbps radios that send data over 100km.
They run at 900Mhz www.microhardcorp.com

They make 54Mbps broadband wireless gear too, quoted range is 16km.

We've used their 900Mhz gear for years, and it's only gotten better, from 1200bps to 1.5Mbps.
Works great in cluttered environments (urban or forest)

Comment: Sexy, no license required to operate?

Comment: The 900Mhz is no-license, the 54MBps is in the WIFI band. (No license either)

Answer (score 4):

A 10km link for 80Mbit/sec? Not going to happen. You're going to have a hell of a problem getting consumer gear to do 10km with one endpoint mobile, let alone 80Mbps.

Why not encode that stream with an FPGA or encoder chip to get it down to a more manageable bit rate? Now you can start looking for high-power commercial gear, but I'm guessing that you won't find anything you can use without a license.  The gear that Tim is talking about is all for fixed point to point links. I've set up some long range 2.4GHz stuff but again, fixed points where you can use a big antenna and jack up the EIRP.

Sorry for the letdown of an answer, but there isn't consumer gear which can do this yet, and the commercial gear will either be pricey or simply unavailable.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think it would be possible, but if it were, it would be awesome. I'm guessing that's why nobody has attempted it and always uses standard definition. Any chance of sending component video?

Comment: The TV stream you get from an antenna is licensed to radiate 10kW(normally directivity gives a 10x multiplier on the power in the directions they have viewers). This allows very long distance transmission. This issue is that to transmit very high def, you need more bandwidth. Most people whom want high high def are just going to buy a cable modem, or get satellite(which is wireless with high def).

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you need to consider in a project like this:

1. What are the wireless regulations for the markets you are planning on selling to? Typically the wireless spectrum is very limited on what frequencies you can use, how much power, and for how long you can broadcast. Of course you can usually pay a licensing fee to go above it, but you would have to look into the rules for the area you would be selling to see if the license is something you can afford for your project.
2. What is the free space and obstacle loss that are associated with the range and environment that you want it to work in? Now how much power will you need in order to go that far?
3. Portable or fixed? How high (elevation wise) will it be? Because of the curvature of the earth, the longer distances you want to go the higher you have to be.
4. Do you want the user to have to aim their antenna or is it going to be omni-directional. How tight of range are you going to have? The tighter the range the higher your effective gain will be on your antenna.
5. Are you going digital or analog? This will effect how you will encode your data, acceptable error amounts and acceptable signal to noise ratio.

I think once you consider these items you will probably realize it isn't practical for a consumer application.

Answer (score 3):

What about using a TCP/IP data link established with some modern mobile phone or modem? I guess GPRS is too slow but 3G might do the job. Mobile phone might even use it's camera and compress the picture for sending, or you can just put it in an automatic answer mode and use it as a simple 3G video phone. This solution might also spare you wireless licensing problems.

Answer (score 0):

First of all compress the data to get the bandwidth down to less than 20 Mb/s, then get long range 5GHz 802.11n radios with directional antennae like these:

http://ubnt.com/

If one end is mobile, then you will need to steer the antennas to keep them pointing in the right direction.

I'd find some low-bandwith + long-range radios that can be used to transmit the GPS position of the rover back to the base to allow the base-antenna to be aimed.

An alternative solution would be to have two radios at either end and scan the second radio around to optimize the aim of the main radio, but mechanically that's quite complicated and heavy.

You might get away with an omnidirectional antenna on the rover and only use a directional antenna on the station, but range will suffer a lot.

Answer (score -3):

Such technology already exists.  Digital, Hi-Def TV transmissions are either 720p or 720i and broadcast over miles.  Do some research into what they use.

Comment: He won't be getting a license for that. :-)  Also ATSC is normally MPEG4-coded and transmitted at 18Mbps, which is a good deal smaller than the 80Mbps which he was looking for.

Comment: I don't understand the vote down, the technology used to transmit 720p video over a long-distance wireless link exists and is used.  Doing research into what equipment and methods they use would be worthwhile.